# Why charge is zero inside a conductor

Tags: charge

When we find electric field for a conductor having closed surface, then we take charge inside conductor zero, because in conductor charge comes on surface due to force between charges. This is what I have studied.

But for an ideal conductor, permittivity is infinite so electrostatic force must be zero inside conductor, then how charges come on surface?

Comment: if we put a charge inside a sperical conductor like at center then what will happen with charge and electric field inside Conductor???

thanks for explaining

Answer (score 2):

The electrostatic field is zero AFTER equilibrium is established (after the internal E-field cancels the external E-field.)

Remember the equation that describes the introduction of charges at some interior point of a given material:

[image]

What it means is that any charge introduced at the interior of the conductor will decay immediately and appear on the the surface.

**Stated in other way, if some charges are introduced in the interior of a conductor, the charges will move to the surface and redistribute themselves quickly in such a manner that the field inside the conductor vanishes.**

Answer (score 0):

> But for an ideal conductor, permittivity is infinite so electrostatic
>   force must be zero inside conductor, then how charges come on surface?

Consider a physical conductor where the mobile charge, assuming an initial configuration of mobile charge inside, relatively quickly respond to the electric field within, rearranging in a such a way that the electric field inside the conductor (effectively) vanishes.

In a physical conductor, due to a variety of factors, this rearrangement does not occur instantly; there is a characteristic [relaxation time](http://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/chapter7/7.7.html) \$\tau_e\$ associated with conductors.

However, we can imagine 'taking the limit' of these factors in such a way that the relaxation time goes to zero to arrive at the abstraction of an *ideal* conductor.

Then, it's easy to see why we say the permittivity is infinite - the charge can redistribute *instantaneously* such that the field inside the conductor is zero regardless of the external electric field.